# find the second word in first line which starts with specific word and replace the next line first word in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a requirement to change the below file in to new file ...

File i have with me ....

```
uid=GESCHELP1, ou=Special Users, dc=domain,dc=com
different: c
        1: IND
different: sn
        1: REC

uid=GESCHELP2, ou=Special Users, dc=domain,dc=com
different: country
        1: USA
different: givenname
        1: Raj
```

The output file should be as follow .......

```
dn: uid=GESCHELP1, ou=Special Users, dc=domain,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: c
c: IND
-
replace: sn
sn: REC

uid=GESCHELP2, ou=Special Users, dc=domain,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: country
country: USA
-
replace: givenname
givenname: Aus
```

Please help me to get the solutions.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service - please provide any solution that you have attempted first.

Comment: Let me *"help [you] to get the solutions."* : You might want to look at the man pages for `sed`, `awk` and `bash-builtins`

Comment: I am beginner in scripting ... so far i have used the below commands to get the below file ...

Comment: sed -n -e  '/2/!p'  -e '/uid/a changetype: modify' -e '/1/a -'  user.ldif
sed -i 's/different/replace/g' user.ldif



and i got the below output ... from here i am unable to replace the string..

uid=GESCHELP1, ou=Special Users, dc=domain,dc=com
changetype: modify
-
replace: c
        1: IND
-
replace: sn
        1: REC
-

changetype: modify
replace: country
        1: USA
-
replace: givenname
        1: Raj
-

Comment: @EugenRieck .... any updates for me .. @ Rakesh

Comment: Any one please help me to get the logic as it is needed bit urgent.

Comment: Hi All, any suggestions for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this command will give the required result

awk -F': *' -v OFS=": " '$1=="replace"{r=$2;print;next}r{$1=r;r=""}7' file